# ResultSet cleared after connection close. SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, java-8, connection, resultset

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Long chatId = 432878720L;
    String what = "*";
    String from = "BtcUser";
    ResultSet rs = selectUser(what, from, chatId);
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("NEVER REACH");
    }
}

private static ResultSet selectUser(String what, String from, long chatId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT "+what+" FROM "+from+" WHERE chatId = ?;";
    ResultSet rs;
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setLong(1, chatId);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        return rs;
    }
}
```

As you guessed, the IF block is always false. But when this code make like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Long chatId = 432878720L;
    String what = "*";
    String from = "BtcUser";
    String sql = "SELECT "+what+" FROM "+from+" WHERE chatId = ?;";
    ResultSet rs;
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setLong(1, chatId);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("HELLO");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works. And IF block can be true.
I guess the ResultSet resets when connection closing. Why this happens and how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out.
The prepared statement must not be closed for saving ResultSet. So this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    long chatId = 432878720L;
    String what = "*";
    String from = "BtcUser";
    ResultSet rs = f(what, from, chatId);
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}

private static ResultSet f(String what, String from, long chatId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT "+what+" FROM "+from+" WHERE chatId = ?;";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setLong(1, chatId);
        return pst.executeQuery();
    }
}
```